How to write indexes in markdown
Does anyone know, can I write k, k+1, ... - letter as indexes, for example the same way like in the picture
k, k+1 - the indexes
I usually wrote just in the form of sk, sk+1... but in this example it looks terrible and it's easy to get this example wrong

Have you tried using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Mathematical_symbols ?

Some markdown editors allow to include latex formulas between $$ ... $$ anchors.

O, thanks, make a copies from wikipedia really helps some time. Haven't worked with latex yet, so can't try this approach for now, but anyway thanks for help, I'll notice if it realy helps
